# WPF keeping control in a perfect rectangle shape (binding width and height)

Tags: wpf, binding, shapes

Currently I am struggling to get a control to be displayed in a box shape in WPF without having to need to result to code. Here is a working example of what I want it to look like:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="3" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Source="http://blog.joeclarmusic.com/images/rss-icon.jpg" />
          <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
      </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="#DDDDDD" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
```

Ok, this is all cool and well. In my current design, I am using ItemsControl and displaying a list of images. Since such a list can exceed the width of the window I wanted to add ScrollViewer around the StackPanel where the VerticalScrollBar is disabled (since I only want it to flow from left to right, I only need the HorizontalScrollBar).

After adding the ScrollViewer:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="3" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
          <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Image Source="http://blog.joeclarmusic.com/images/rss-icon.jpg" />
          <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0, 5, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
         </Grid>    
        </Button>
      </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="#DDDDDD" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
```

Image of the above when running in kaxaml 1.7.1 in my computer: jonatan.nilsson.is/wpf_with_scrollviewer.jpg

If you run it in Kaxaml (or in a WPF window/page) your [button will now keep on getting bigger and bigger (both width and height)](http://jonatan.nilsson.is/wpf_with_scrollviewer.jpg). The only change I have done is add ScrollViewer around the StackPanel. everything else is the same so why does it keep on getting bigger when inside a scrollviewer?

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
Added an image of the outcome from the second example.

Comment: You forgot to add <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" . But I don't know what the question is, because your two samples seem to be equivalent.

Comment: Then you should look closer. The second example contains ScrollViewer while the previous example doesn't. While this doesn't seem much of a change to you, trust me, the end result is on a whole different level. In the second example, the button will grow infinitely and infinitely fast automatically. Try it in Kaxaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. This "behavior" occurs if the following condition are met:

- The content of the button contains an image
- The width/height has binding to it's height/width.
- The button content is higher than it's width (when the binding is set to height->width)

You can test this very easily. If you remove everything inside the Button.Content except for the image, the whole thing "almost" works (the button will not become smaller if you make the row height smaller using the GridSplitter but it will grow bigger).

However if you then add `Margin="0, 0, 0, 1"` to the Image, then the same behavior occurs as before (that is, it grows infinitely).

What is happening is basically this:

1. Button height is higher than it's width.
2. Binding sees it and makes it wider
3. The Image sees it's gotten wider and makes itself higher in order to keep it's ratio (in this case 1:1)
4. The Image pushes itself higher.
5. The Button height is higher than it's width, go to step 2.

Basically, because the behavior of the image is to always keep it's ratio. To work around this "behavior" is to make the Button content's be wider than it is in height. If the Button contents width is higher than it's height, then the Binding will force it's width lower. This somehow makes the image behave correctly.

In my second example, adding for example this:

```
Margin="30 ,0"
```

To Image will fix the issue of it's never-ending growth.

I'm not sure if I explained this very well so please comment if you have suggestions that might improve this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
OK, I have fiddled with your code a bit, and I can confirm that the button is indeed growing infinitely large.  I can't really say why this is happening.  Probably some internal measurement is getting borked.  I did find that using any panel control as the button content (Grid in this case) will cause the problem, as will a StackPanel or DockPanel and so on.  Perhaps you would be better off by not putting these items in a button, and use some other control instead.  Does it really need to be a button?

OLD:
The height of the button keeps getting bigger, probably because the grid cell itself keeps getting bigger.  If you use the grid splitter to resize the grid components, then the button will assume the entire height of the cell that it resides in.  Maybe it would make more sense if you were to explain the circumstances under which it 'keeps getting bigger'  Come to think of it, if this is something that is to reside in an items control, why the grid splitter and empty cell in the first place?

OLDER:
By 'will now overflow the height keep getting bigger' I assume that you mean the width as well as the height of your button.  Well that is because you have the width bound directly to the height.

If you mean 'will NOT overflow....' well that is another story altogether having to do with the size of your grid rows.  Perhaps you should clarify what your actual problem is, and maybe provide some valid XAML as an example. (The XAML in your post is missing a '' tag in the button content.

Comment: Sorry, apparently <Grid> was missing from the Button.Content. I fixed the code and hopefully fixed the description on my problem.

Comment: sorry, the fixed XAML still doesn't indicate what you are trying to do.  From my standpoint everything is fine.  There is a button with an image inside of a ScrollViewer.  It is all inside of a 'box' shape.

Comment: When I run it in my computer (in kaxaml 1.7.1) The button is much larger than the scrollviewer. Here's an image of the first example without scrollviewer (what I want the results to be like): http://jonatan.nilsson.is/wpf_no_scrollviewer.jpg and here is an image from my computer when I add ScrollViewer around the StackPanel (second example): http://jonatan.nilsson.is/wpf_with_scrollviewer.jpg

Comment: Just to note, the control was growing infinitely large. I had to add MaxWidth="1000" just to stop it from growing infinitely.

Comment: Yes, unless there is another control that provides click support, it has to be a Button. I could bind the Button height property to the ScrollViewer.ActualHeight and it would prevent the control from growing infinitely.

However if I remove the Panel Control from the Button and just keep the image as the button content, even then it doesn't work 100%. The button will only grow and not shrink when the height changes. If you move the GridSplitter down, the button will grow. If you move the GridSplitter up, the button will retain it's current size and not shrink accordingly.

This is a weird bug.

Comment: The gridsplitter thing you are describing is not a bug, but more just how the mechanics of grid cells work in conjunction with the splitter.  Meanwhile, just about everything in WPF can be given 'click support' by capturing normal mouse events.  If you are looking for command support on the other hand, you will have to stick with the button, or make a user control or something that exposes a command.  It would probably just be easiest to catch an event on the image, and use that for the user action.

Comment: Actually, if you look at my answer, you will see that adding Margin to the image will make the button bigger and smaller in conjunction to the height of the grid cell and make my example and my objective work.